# Swift compression zlib level=1 - or if default compression level is to good

Tags: swift, zlib

know anyone a Swift library to compress with zlib algorithm level=1 ?

Apple only support level=5 with COMPRESSION_ZLIB but sometime - now - I need exactly a different level in result of compatibility with existing world (programs).

Thx

---

I need same as
`zlib-flate -compress=1 <inputFile >outputFile`

Comment: You can install zlib via Homebrew on your Mac and then use it in your project.

Comment: Yes, I can qpdf install with brew, but so I need to create processes from inside my Swift program. Maybe a solution, but not good solution. I did not understand why Apple only support compression with level 5 and uncompression with all level.

Comment: I don't know why Apple does not provide a way to set the compression level, but on the decompression side, all levels are always supported. The decompressor has no idea what the compression level was, and doesn't care.

Comment: @MarkAdler thats OK. Apache make same with xz algorithm and implements only what they want. Problems come with world beside their own focus. For example git need zlib level 1 and some developer want xz with max compression.
Both compression types are perhaps not state of the art of possible compressions with today knowledge and hardware but still existing and used...